# Rendering many partials in rails (500+) is slow

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I made a partial of a for a song model with `artist`, `title`, `duration`, `release` etc.

I want to show all the artists songs on one page, sometimes they have a ton.  The query takes 0.08 seconds, but I also see this:

```
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (18.2ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (8.5ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (7.5ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (9.6ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (18.6ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (12.6ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (7.8ms)
Rendered artist/_song_listing.html.haml (19.5ms)
```

(etc etc)

Ultimately this takes 14 seconds, which is way too long.

Is it wrong to use partials in this way?  Is there any way to make this faster?

Edit:

ArtistController:

```
  def show

    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    @songs = @artist.songs.order('published_at DESC').includes(:members)
```

show.html.haml:

```
  .panel.panel-default
    - @artist.songs.each do |song|
      =render 'song_listing', song: song
```

Exerpt from `_song_listing` (~500 times):

```
.row
  .col-xs-12
    .summary
      -if song.summary.present?
        ="#{song.summary.sanitize.strip.gsub("\u00A0"," ")}"
      -else
        %i
          No Summary

.row
  .col-xs-10
    %ul.list-inline
      - song.members.each do |member|
        %li
          %span
            %img{src:"#{member.image_url}", width: '20px', height: '20px', class: 'img-circle'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the load coming from the SQL queries? Try pre-loading in your controller.

```
@songs = Song.all.includes(:artist,:title)
```

Then something like

```
@songs.each do |song|
  # render logic here for each song
end
```

In the includes you would put any related associations, which are not loaded automatically.

This should make each partial rendering much faster, if SQL queries were your problem.

**Further instructions to include from the first look up:**

```
@artist = Artist.find(params[:id]).includes(:songs => [:members])
@songs = @artist.songs.order('published_at DESC')
```

I believe this will do the trick for you. However what you had earlier would still be OK. Not sure if the brackets around ":members" are required, but essentially you are saying, include Artist's songs, and for each song include it's members.

Comment: I updated the question.  Is that how I use includes?  Could I even do an includes earlier with the artist lookup?

Comment: @Ashbury You're on the right track for sure. Check out your Rails log to see the difference in the SQL queries, if you'd like to see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been ages, but I thought an improvement to the current answers might help others as well

```
  .panel.panel-default
    =render partial: 'song_listing', collection: @artist.songs, as: :song
```

This is much faster in terms of rendering. not as fast as inline rendering, but much better than doing a render for each item.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are possibly doing a database lookup for each song. Try to load all the song data in a single query. It may also help to post your view code if indeed the rendering is the bottleneck.